# Open PDF File with Adobe Acrobat inside Java Application (via OLE)

Tags: java, eclipse, adobe, ole, acrobat-sdk

I would like to open a PDF File inside an existing Java(SWT)-Application. The PDF should not opened in an external frame. I tried via the OLE interface but without success.

```
clientSite = new OleControlSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "AcroExch.App", fileName);
automation = new OleAutomation(clientSite);
clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_OPEN);
```

Comment: I want to use Adobe Acrobat DC, because i need the screen reader option

Answer (score 0):

you can use the IE Interface and then navigate to the PDF file.

Pseudocode:

```
$Obj = ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")
$Obj.Navigate('D:\Test.pdf')
```

or the Reader Web Interface

Pseudocode:

```
$oReader = ObjCreate("AcroPDF.PDF.1")
$oReader.Load("D:\Test.pdf")
```

How you bind the object into your Java-GUI you may ask under java
HTH, Reinhard

PS: the "Shell.Explorer.2" option mostly works for me better.